# R gputools: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wp’

Tags: r, gcc, gpu, nvcc

I had an error when I install `gputools` in R, and I cannot find any solution by google.
I use command `install.packages("gputools")`

```
  /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -c -Xcompiler "-fpic -I/usr/local/include -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic" -I. -I"/usr/local/cuda/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" rinterface.cu -o rinterface.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wp’
make: *** [rinterface.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gputools’
```

Can someone help me here? My gpu cards is given by

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K620] (rev a2)
```

Comment: What about removing the offending comma/agreement from the host compiler options you are passing to the compiler?

Comment: @talonmies. I do not understand what you mean. I use command `install.packages("gputools")` in R console.

Comment: So the setup of that R package contains compiler options that are being passed to your host gcc, which it does not understand. Either remove them yourself, or report this to the person who made the package. I see no CUDA programming question here, so I will remove the tag

Comment: @MikeBrown. Just curious. did you ever figure this out. I'm running into the same issue. I'm trying to run this on centos 7.

Comment: @BillMan. I did not figure this out. And I am still looking for solution.

Comment: @MikeBrown. May to to see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got this working with a couple hacks. This is for centos 7.

First issue was solved by looking at the mailing list.  https://github.com/nullsatz/gputools/issues/12

**Edit the Makefile, and Modify line 'CFLAGS :  put '\' after 'Wp' & before ','**

CFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp\,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic

Second problem was that the R shared lib was not being found. I tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the driver configuration file, and on the command line, but that did not work.

I ended up with the following hack:

**cd /usr/local/cuda/lib64 &&  ln -s  /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so libR.so**

I used the command following to build (note the tar.gz file now contains the modified Makefile)

**R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nvcc=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --with-r-lib=/usr/lib64/" ./gputools_1.0.tar.gz**

I know this is ugly, but it seems to work.

Comment: After you put '\' after 'Wp' & before ',', what did you do with the folder `gputools`?  Did you zip it again? If I install packages from the tar.gz file, it shows the same error.

Comment: I can't find where the Makefile is. Even when I run 'grep -r "Wp" .' from inside the unzipped file. Where is the Makefile, or how can I generate it?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your makefile has a typo

```
-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

Specifically, the comma (',') should be a space (' ') only.

Please try that and report back letting us know what happened

Comment: It works. The problem is how to install the package. From the unzip folder `gputools` or tar.gz file again?